# Using 'az webapp deploy' to deploy .war file to subfolder

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, geoserver

I have created a Linux App Service with Java8 and Tomcat 8.5 in Azure.

To that App Service I deploy a .war file using the following command:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path ./geoserver.war
```

This all works fine. This uploads my `.war` file to the `/home/site/wwwroot/` directory and gives the war file the name `app.war` by default.

Then I can access:

```
https://[my-site].azurewebsites.net/web
```

And it all works. The site loads.

But I need it to be in a subfolder, so I can navigate to something like:

```
https://[my-site].azurewebsites.net/geoserver/web/
```

So I changed my command a little by adding `--target-path` to it. But whatever path I try, I keep getting this error back:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

When I remove the `--target-path` command, then it works fine.

My command end up looking like this:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path ./geoserver.war --target-path /home/site/wwwroot/geoserver/
```

But, this gives me the error shown above. I've tried the following things as `--target-path`, but all fail with the same error:

```
--target-path /home/site/wwwroot/geoserver/
--target-path /home/site/wwwroot/geoserver
--target-path /home/site/wwwroot/geoserver/app.war
--target-path /geoserver/
--target-path /geoserver/app.war
--target-path home/site/wwwroot/geoserver/app.war
--target-path /site/wwwroot/geoserver/
etc..
```

So basically my goal is to deploy the `.war` file to a subfolder. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: App requiring a different path for unpacking. Requires the following at the end of the path. "/api/wardeploy?name=newpath"


You may check the `wardeploy`  - By default, `wardeploy` deploys to the ROOT app. As per your requirement, you may use the query parameter name to specify the name of the app you want to deploy to: /api/wardeploy?name=NAME_OF_APP. For example, /api/wardeploy?name=myapp will deploy to the /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/myapp directory instead of /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT. [see](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-WAR-files-using-wardeploy)

Comment: @Vivendi - Any update regarding the issue ?